# vector of objects to use with a vector of pointers

Tags: c++, gsoap, std

The proxy objects generated by gSoap indicate that I should use a vector of pointers:

```
class SOAP_CMAC ota__RoomStayTypeRoomRates
{
public:
    std::vector<class ota__RoomRateType * >RoomRate;
    //....
};
```

Rather than using:

```
vector.push_back(new Object());
```

and then having to delete the objects, I thought I might create a vector of objects and then use the address of those objects as they will be destroyed when the vector goes out of scope, thereby avoiding memory leaks:

```
OTARoomRates roomRates;

std::vector<ota__RoomRateType> rateObjectList;

rateObjectList.reserve(7);
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    rateObjectList[i].RoomTypeCode = &roomTypeCode;
    rateObjectList[i].RatePlanID = &ratePlanID;
    //...
    roomRates.RoomRate.push_back(&rateObjectList[i]);
}
```

I get a segfault. I suppose it's a bad idea. Can you explain why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rateObjectList.reserve(7)` doesn't actually allocate or construct any `ota__RoomRateType` objects; it simply requests that the vector expand its capacity enough to hold 7 objects.

Potentially, you wanted `rateObjectList.resize(7)`. Or `std::vector<ota__RoomRateType> rateObjectList(7);` if you know the number at vector creation time.

Comment: Thanks! That was the problem... (waiting 3 minutes to accept the answer.)

Answer (score 0):

> Can you explain why?

Sure. If someone holds `roomRates` when `rateObjectList` destroyed then any attempt to use a pointer from `roomRates` can cause `SEG_FAULT`. That's a bad idea, anyway.

This is better in this case

```
vector.push_back(new Object());
```

Even better is to use smart-pointers, like `boost::shared_ptr`

Comment: boost is nice and all, but I think it might not be possible to use with the gSoap generated classes. It's only for generating an SOAP request. So both vectors are in the same scope.